# "The gap we had to climb was over 2 hundred feet high. "

Tags: word-usage

> The ***gap*** we had to climb was over 2 hundred feet high.

My question is why it is not correct to use the word "gap" in this sentence? If "gap" is not correct in this sentence, which word will be good to use here?

Answer (score 1):

The word high doesn't usually describe a gap, which is an opening, an absence, or a depression. The word does have a meaning as a pass through mountains, and in that case, it could be said to have a height, that is a height above the elevation one is at, though it is much lower than the surrounding mountains. For that particular meaning, it would be more likely to be put like this:

> The gap we had to climb through was over two hundred feet high.

For the other uses, referring to an opening or depression, some more apt expressions would be

> The gap we had to climb over was two hundred feet wide.
> The gap we had to bridge was over two hundred feet deep.

A word that could be used in place of **gap** in that sentence might be **hill** or **cliff**.